# change version of android application file

Tags: android, eclipse

I developed one application in android 3.1. But my phone version is 2.2.1.how can i change the version of my apk file to 2.2.1.When i installed in my phone it shows an error"problem parsing the package".Can anybody help me for this

Answer (score 1):

I can't see the point of runing your app on 2.2.1 in your app is specified to run on 3.1+. If you want to change  the lowest target version from eclipse, right click on your project and:

```
Properties > Android > Android 2.2
```

Don't forget to change your manifest as well:

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You can provide it in manifest like this,

```
        <uses-sdk android:targetSdkVersion="8" android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:maxSdkVersion="10" android:minSdkVersion="5">
</uses-sdk>
```

Since your mobile is of version 2.2.1 it means that it belongs to API level 8.

Answer (score 0):

Also note that if within your app you used certain features / functions which were only introduced in the higher version SDK then they may work unexpectedly once you switch over to a lower SDK version. This can be taken care of via compatibility package.